# Titanium HTTPClient - TSL connections sometimes get "lost" von Android (not on iOS)

Tags: android, ssl, titanium

This is an very, very strange problem.
We got an app based on Titanium SDK (version 7.4.1 I think), which gets it's data via an API to from our servers. These connections are running with TSL and basically, it works. But: Some connections do not receive data, they just run into a timeout.
I did some debug on this and this resulted in an even more strange thing: The working connections work really fine, but the non-working doing strange things. App connects to the server, server sends ACK. After this, app sends a ClientHello and receives an ACK - but nothing follows. The app is waiting for the ServerHello until the connections times out. This is all from a tcpdump.
So I created the same dump on server side, and here it starts to get really strange: For the non-working connections, the initial handshake is there. But the ClientHello is not received by the server.

This leaves me baffled, because the app is getting an ACK for sent ClientHello. Who TF is sending this, when the server never received any? It's an VM within a larger cluster - maybe it's ACKed before it reaches the VM?

Because I mentioned Titanium as well: The problem ONLY occures on Android. The iOS version of the app (with same code) is not affected!

Any ideas from anyone? All input is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try a newer SDK? 7.4.1 was released Oct. 2018. Since you are saying that some of the connections work it hard to say, never experienced that kind of connection but my API endpoints are mostly normal web-hosting spaces